# Inputs being returned as undefined and not working with x & y position on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm working on a program that makes a ball bounce around a canvas at a speed determined by the user with two inputs, x velocity and y velocity. It returns the users values as undefined even though I'm converting the string to an integer to be used in the balls position. I've been working on this for the last few days and I'm sure its something really simple to fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.onload= function()
        {
            document.getElementById("changeButton").onclick = draw;
        }

    function draw(){
        //alert("Hey you made it!" + "\n" + "dx: " + dx + "\n" + "dy: " + dy); //alert which returns dx and dy for following stack    commented out when not in use otherwise alert happens every 10 ms

    //variables
        var hVel = parseInt(document.getElementById("hVelocityBox").value, 10); //gets value for x movement and converts from string to int
        var vVel = parseInt(document.getElementById("vVelocityBox").value, 10); //gets value for y movement and converts from string to int
        var dx= hVel;
        var dy= vVel;
        var y=150; //default x position
        var x=150; //default y posiiton
        var context = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

     //refreshes the canvas
        context.clearRect(0,0,300,300);

    //draws circle
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle="#0000ff";
        context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();

    //code for movement
        if( x<0 || x>300) //position limiter in x
            dx=-dx; //reverses x movement
        if( y<0 || y>300) //position limiter in y
            dy=-dy; //reverses y movement

        x+=dx; //
        y+=dy;
    }//close draw
    setInterval(draw,10); //runs draw every 10 ms 
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>HTML5 Bouncing Ball</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bouncing a Ball Around with HTML5 and JavaScript</h1>
    <div id="container">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas><br/>

    <!--Textfields for x and y velocities, values defaulted to 4 -->
        Horizontal Velocity <input id="hVelocityBox" type="text" value="4"/><br />
        Vertical Velocity <input id="vVelocityBox" type="text" value="4"/><br />

        <button id="changeButton">Change</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues you had here. You basically kept resetting the position and the velocity every time that the function ran. I moved the declaration and initialization of those out of the draw function. I also added an update function to bind to the button. This allows you to update without interfering with the draw function. You may want to consider a more guaranteed way of keeping the ball inside the box (I included that in some comments).

Here's a fiddle with it working correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/azurelogic/yz7LF/14/

```
document.getElementById("changeButton").onclick = update;
var y=150; //default x position
var x=150; //default y posiiton
var dx = parseInt(document.getElementById("hVelocityBox").value, 10); //gets value for x movement and converts from string to int
var dy = parseInt(document.getElementById("vVelocityBox").value, 10); //gets value for y movement and converts from string to int

function update(){
    x = 150;
    y = 150;
    dx = parseInt(document.getElementById("hVelocityBox").value, 10); //gets value for x movement and converts from string to int
    dy = parseInt(document.getElementById("vVelocityBox").value, 10); //gets value for y movement and converts from string to int
}

function draw(){
    var context = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

    //refreshes the canvas
    context.clearRect(0,0,300,300);

    //draws circle
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle="#0000ff";
    context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();

    //code for movement
    if( x<0 || x>300) //position limiter in x
    {
       //these may help prevent accidental escapes
       //if (x<0) x = 0;
       //if (x>300) x = 300;
        dx=-dx; //reverses x movement
    }
    if( y<0 || y>300) //position limiter in y
    {
        //these may help prevent accidental escapes
        //if (y<0) y = 0;
        //if (y>300) y = 300;
        dy=-dy; //reverses y movement
    }
    x+=dx; 
    y+=dy;
};//close draw

setInterval(draw,10); //runs draw every 10 ms
```

Comment: +1 Good solution. You might want to adjust for the radius of the ball with `if( x<20 || x>280)` and `if( y<20 || y>280)` so the ball doesn't appear to bounce through the walls.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work thanks to your help! The main issue I ended up having without really realizing it was not waiting to run the Js till the html had been completely loaded. Using window.onload = function() wasn't seeming to work so my fix ended up being coding the HTML before the JS. Is this a decent fix or is it an amature fix?

Comment: You could hook to the onload event of the canvas itself, or pull in jQuery and use its document.ready. Also, if you look at things like pagespeed recommendations, non-essential JS should be below the fold content anyway.